# Indy's TIdHTTPProxyServer: all traffic should run over a specific IP

Tags: delphi, proxy, indy

Suppose I have a server with multiple IP addresses. Is it possible to use a specific IP for external requests (something like BoundIP of TIdHTTP) ?

Comment: The client is configured to connect to a specific IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want inbound traffic to come from specific network adapter(s), use the `TIdHTTPProxyServer.Bindings` property to setup your desired listening port(s) for those adapter(s) before activating the server.

If you want outbound traffic to be sent out from a specific network adapter, then inside the `TIdHTTPProxyServer.OnHTTPBeforeCommand` event, you can type-cast the `AContext.OutboundClient` property to `TIdTCPClient` and then set its `BoundIP` property.